# Trying to update the database using the strapi.db.query even providing data, failed with "Update required data object"

Tags: strapi

Below is the code that I tried to update the database using the id,

```
try {
            await strapi.db.query("api::otp.otp").update(otpSent.id, {
              where: { otpSent },
              data,
            });
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
```

but I am stuck at the error saying
Error: Update requires a data object.
I have checked the entity-manager.js to see arguments are correct. But, at last  I do not get any idea to update the query. Please give some tips to me to figure this out. The only thing is to update the database entries by id in the strapi controller.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I should use

```
strapi.service("api::otp.otp").update(otpSent.id, { data: data })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way:

```
await strapi.db.query('api::otp.otp').update(
                {
                    where: { id: otpSent.id },
                    data: {
                        anyField: 'updatedData'
                    },
                })
```